# Nativescript procudes bootstrap: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[EffectSources -> ErrorHandler]:

Tags: angular, nativescript, rxjs6

When I run the app using "tns run android --emulator", I encounter the error below

> Successfully synced application org.nativescript.ema on device
>   emulator-5554. ActivityManager: Start proc
>   1005:org.nativescript.ema/u0a90 for activity
>   org.nativescript.ema/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity JS: Sam Activity
>   Event: activityCreated, Activity:
>   com.tns.NativeScriptActivity@2689395, Bundle: null JS: Launched
>   Android application with the following intent: Intent { flg=0x10000000
>   cmp=org.nativescript.ema/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity }. JS:
>   bootstrap: ERROR BOOTSTRAPPING ANGULAR JS: bootstrap:
>   StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[EffectSources -> ErrorHandler]: JS:
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[EffectSources -> ErrorHandler]:
>   JS:     NullInjectorError: No provider for ErrorHandler! JS: JS:
>   Error: NullInjectorError: No provider for ErrorHandler! JS:     at
>   NullInjector.get
>   (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ema/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1035:19)
>   [angular] JS:     at resolveToken
>   (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ema/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1279:24)
>   [angular] JS:     at tryResolveToken
>   (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ema/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1224:16)
>   [angular] JS:     at StaticInjector.get
>   (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ema/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1119:20)
>   [angular] JS:     at resolveToken
>   (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ema/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1279:24)
>   [angular] JS:     at tryResolveToken
>   (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ema/files/app/tns_mod... JS: Sam
>   Activity Event: activityStarted, Activity:
>   com.tns.NativeScriptActivity@2689395 JS: Resume Event Activity:
>   com.tns.NativeScriptActivity@2689395 JS: Sam Activity Event:
>   activityResumed, Activity: com.tns.NativeScriptActivity@2689395

Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "ema",
  "description": "Employer Maid Agency",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.ema",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "4.1.2"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.4",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^6.0.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^6.0.1",
    "nativescript-angular": "^6.0.0",
    "nativescript-background-http": "^3.2.7",
    "nativescript-camera": "^4.0.2",
    "nativescript-fancyalert": "^1.2.0",
    "nativescript-feedback": "^1.2.0",
    "nativescript-loading-indicator": "^2.4.0",
    "nativescript-ngx-fonticon": "^4.2.0",
    "nativescript-snackbar": "^3.1.0",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "^1.0.4",
    "ramda": "^0.25.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "^4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^0.6.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.4",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^6.0.8",
    "babel-traverse": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-types": "^6.26.0",
    "babylon": "^6.18.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "~0.1.19",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "lazy": "^1.0.11",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.7.1",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^0.12.0",
    "nativescript-worker-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.3",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.5",
    "webpack": "^4.12.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.13.1",
    "webpack-cli": "~2.1.3",
    "webpack-sources": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

I try to search for the solution online but it seems it has never be reported before. I struggle for the whole morning but I am not to solve it. If you do require source code, do let me know.

I am much appreciate if you can guide me "where" should I look into.

thanks in advance.

Comment: `StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[EffectSources -> ErrorHandler]: JS: NullInjectorError: No provider for ErrorHandler` means that you didn't import `ErrorHandler` in `EffectSources` module. If this doesn't speak to you, it means one of your libraries wasn't installed properly.

Comment: I find out the issue as follow. Just import NativesScriptModule in app.module.ts and import { NativeScriptCommonModule } from "nativescript-angular/common" in other feature or share modules.